# Shortwiring a PSU WITHOUT Paper clip

Tags: power-supply, motherboard

So, in a haste to power up the PSU after the paper clip test, I cut all the wires from the 24 pin connector and tried to connect the green and the black wires directly. However, the fan on the PSU just moves a little bit every time I connect those two wires but the PSU doesn't turn on completely.

More details:
This is a 200W Solid Gear PSU.
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00C2PM8JW/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s04?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C2PM8JW)

The fans are 12V at 0.2A.
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00B2ARV22/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s04?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B2ARV22)

Here is exactly what I need:

I need to connect five of the above mentioned 12V fans to the PSU.

Comment: If it doesn’t work, get a new one.

Comment: I've already cut the wires. Can't return it. Why won't it work?

Comment: I never said you should return it. And thanks to capitalism, you don’t have to! That being said, it’s probably broken. Can also be the case for newly bought stuff.

Comment: you probably don't make a reliable connection, or your psu is fried. what's a paperclip test anyway?

Comment: @VladimirCravero The [paperclip test](http://dodji.seketeli.com/downloads/shuttle-psu-paper-clip-test.pdf) is shorting the green wire (`PS_ON#` or power supply on) signal to ground to turn the PSU on.

Comment: Maybe there's a short somewhere that is tripping the PSU short circuit protection.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd paid careful attention to the wiring of the ATX plug you may have noticed that one of the ground connections had 2 wires going into it instead of one.  Alternatively one of the +3.3V pins may have had 2 wires going into it instead of one.  Some even have both (depending on the manufacturer's design).

These extra wires aren't power wires, they are sense wires - used for monitoring the voltage and/or load on the PSU.  Without them connected the PSU will assume there is a fault and shut itself down.

If you can work out which wires are which from your bundle (the sense wires will often be thinner than the power wires, but coloured the same) you may be able to re-attach them to the right voltage points to reactivate your PSU.

Next time pay more attention to the wiring of the plug and don't be so hasty.

Answer (score 0):

It requires a "load": if it can't sense anything that will use the current will not start.
Connect a dvd, a harddisk or something that will use some hunderd mA (milli Ampere).

Warning: dont connect a working harddisk with data if you are not sure that the PSU is working inside the specifications because you risk it!

A resistor or a small bulb also will work.

Edit:
You wrote that "cut" all the wires so I think that you cutted apart also the "+3.3V sense" line.
See pin 13 in the image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Power_supply 
Connected to pin 13 there was two wires! They must remain connected!

Comment: I already connected 3 0.2A fans. Doesn't work!

Comment: Forget to explain: usually the load must be on 5V. Maybe your fans are at 12V.

Comment: Yes, the fans are 12V. How do I rectify the problem?

Comment: You can try to connect two fans to 5V: probably they will not start but if the load is sufficient the 3rd will start.
The light bulb of a bicycle also will works.

Comment: I connected three fans just now. It still does the same thing.

Comment: If the fans are rated 12V it's possible that doesn't load the PSU.
Try something else.
Remember that the PSU can be broken :(

Answer (score 0):

The PSU has 5V and 12V connectors. The 12V is the 4pin connector.

I just used a paper clip to short-wire the PSU (between the green and one of the many black wires in the 24 pin connector. It doesn't need a load. It works without load and starts instantly with the paper clip test without any attached devices at its ends.)

I paralleled wired five 12V fans and used a 4pin to molex adapter to attach the paralleled fans to the 4pin connector.

So attach the paralleled fans to the 4pin to molex adapter (use only the red and black wires) and attach this adapter to the 4pin on the PSU, and BOOM it works!